# Simple way to plot PWM over time

Tags: arduino, pwm

I want to plot the PWM emitted by pin 9 and read by pin 0 in a static PWM signal (like an oscilloscope can do). Is there a simple way to do that?

```
int pwm = 254;
float pulse1;

void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(9, pwm);
  pulse1 = pulseIn(0, pwm);

  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
//  Serial.println(pulse1);  
}
```

I am using an Arduino Uno.

Comment: Maybe try ee or iot if no answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I assume these are arduino forums? I am not familiar with these acronyms. Would you write down the full names? Thank you vm

Comment: The [arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ "https://arduino.stackexchange.com/") might also be helpful

Comment: fanduin suggestion too . Ee is electrical engineering and iot internet of things stack exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to graph the data you receive through the serial monitor. If it is so, you can print a comma after each value -> save the output of the serial monitor to a file with CSV extension -> open the file with MS Excel (or similar)